# Python: Finding the value of a character in a string

Tags: python, string

Given a long string such as:

```
"fkjdlfjzgjkdsheiwqueqpwnvkasdakpp"
```

or

```
"0.53489082304804918409853091868095809846545421135498495431231"
```

How do I find the value of the nth character in that string? I could solve this if I could convert it into a list (where each digit gets it's own index) but since the numbers aren't separated by commas I don't know how to do this either.

AFAIK there is no command like `string.index(10)` which would return the 11th character in.

Comment: Strings are indexable just like lists. `myString[5]` will return the 6th character. Also, if for some reason you wanted to make it into a list anyways, `list(myString)` will make a list in the way you mention.

Comment: How about `a[n]` to get character number `n`?

Comment: both strings and lists are implemented using arrays.

Comment: You should work your way through the Python Tutorial http://docs.python.org/tutorial/ as it answers a lot of these questions. In particular http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#strings will tell you all about subscripting and slicing strings.

Comment: also: `my_str.index('c')` **is** a method which will find the index of a substring.

Comment: Thanks, I had done the tutorials, but I must have missed that. Too long overcomplicating the problem by looking through the python library.

Comment: could you select an answer for your problem?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

strings are like lists. so you can access them the same way,

```
>>> a = "fkjdlfjzgjkdsheiwqueqpwnvkasdakpp"
>>> print a[10]
k
```

Answer (score 5):

Strings are iterable and indexable (since it is a [sequence type](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange)), so you can just use:

```
"fkjdlfjzgjkdsheiwqueqpwnvkasdakpp"[10]
```

Answer (score 2):

**To get the corresponding character in the `nth` value, just use this function:**

```
def getchar(string, n):
    return str(string)[n - 1]
```

**Example usage:**

```
>>> getchar('Hello World', 5)
'o'
```